# How to add Plugin functionality in WordPress Frontend Menus

Tags: plugin-development, menus

In Plugin, I have made Custom Category for Products. Its Simply CRUD for Category and Category Wise Products.

So now i want to add these Categories in WordPress Frontend Menus. So it can be used for frontend.

So how can i do this?

[image]

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of registering taxonomy, make sure you use the [`show_in_nav_menus`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#parameters) parameter and set it true.

For Example:

```
 $args = array(
        'label'             => __( 'book', 'textdomain' ),
        'public'            => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'book', 'with_front' => true),
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
    );

register_taxonomy( 'book', 'products', $args);
```

Comment: No, it is not a texonomy. I want it in plugin. and it includes custom tables and custom insert, Update, Delete For Category. So i want this Category in Menu, Not Taxonomy..!!